# SP-API Amazon ad python library PYTHON-AMAZON-SP-API for upload feed POST_FLAT_FILE_PRICEANDQUANTITYONLY_UPDATE_DATA

Tags: python, amazon-selling-partner-api

For migrating from MWS to SP_API I'm using the library python PYTHON-AMAZON-SP-API's. Some operations I can do like the inventory retrieval, order retrieval.
While the use of Feeds is not clear to me.
Does anyone have a simple example of creating and submitting a fedd to update pric e and quantity (POST_FLAT_FILE_PRICEANDQUANTITYONLY_UPDATE_DATA)